# Sublime Text 2 and bin paths

Tags: sublimetext2

If I print my `$PATH` in a terminal (zsh) I get:

```
λ echo $PATH
/Users/jviotti/.nvm/v0.11.13/bin:/Users/jviotti/bin/Sencha/Cmd/4.0.2.67:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/sbin:/opt/bin:/Users/jviotti/bin:/home/jviotti/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin
```

However if I print the environment variables from Sublime Text 2 console I only get:

```
>>> print(os.environ['PATH'])
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/jviotti/bin
```

Sublime Text 2 detects that I'm using Zsh, however most of my paths are missing.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you launch Sublime via the command line with the `subl` command, it picks up your current `PATH` from your shell. However, files launched from the GUI have a separate `PATH`, and this is what needs to be changed. Please check out [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/89076/19512) over at Unix.SE for detailed instructions on how to set the `PATH` for OS X programs launched via the Dock or Finder. This has only been tested on Mountain Lion (there is a different method for Lion), and while it should work on Mavericks I can't guarantee it. It does require having admin privileges.

Briefly, you need to edit `/etc/launchd.conf` (or create it if it doesn't exist) to include all the entries you want, then restart your computer for the changes to take effect. Keep in mind that this will affect **all** GUI programs, not just Sublime, so if you start getting unexplained behavior or errors, this may be the reason.

Good luck!